# Is there an application that can intercept data between a login interface and a database server?

Tags: security, hash, salt, legacy, man-in-the-middle

I wish to extract login details entered into a web interface and alter them before they reach the database server.  This is for a project where the intention is to create an app that allows for more secure passwords that are salted and hashed (for use on legacy systems).

- I have created a WAMP server and have the webpages and database linked and operational.
- I have written a Java app to make the required changes to the passwords.

**Problem**

I thought I could use RESTful services to extract the username and password, but it didn't work.

Is there any app that will allow me to do this?

I'm apprehensive to stage a Man in the Middle attack as it kind of defeats the purpose of making the system more secure.  Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly you're wanting to achieve? Could you simply not use JavaScript to alter the details?

Comment: As part of a project, I am trying to build an application that operates as a 'quick fix' for legacy systems that store passwords in plain text.  I hoped I could extract the username and password for newly created accounts before they reached the db.  I would then use my Java app to salt, hash and iterate the password.  This would also need to occur for subsequent logins.  I know this can be done by altering the PHP files, but I am trying to avoid making any changes to the existing system.  I'm starting to think this is not possible without performing an MITM, and even then may not be feasible.

Comment: This sounds like you'd be putting a plaster (band aid?) over a gunshot wound. I've never seen an application use plain text passwords before so I'd recommend fixing immediately with the proper fix. As you said use salt and hash. Are you also using http? If so I'd recommend https otherwise you'll be susceptible to packet sniffers on same network.

Comment: Hi yes, I agree absolutely.  According to my research a large proportion of SMEs store user account passwords in plain text.  This was simply a project to assess if a quick fix was attainable.  I'm thinking it's not, as staging a MITM attack to help 'secure' a system is a little convoluted and contradictory.  I still may have to carry out the attack to finish out the project though.  Have you any suggestions for how to stage an automated MITM that links a web server and a java app? Thanks for your reply btw

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to do this, possibly post again with the intention to reproduce a MITM attack and hopefully someone else will be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your help